# написать функцию, принимающую два массива. Создать словарь, в котором элементы из arr_1 будут ключами, а из arr_2 значениями

Tags: python

```
def func(arr_1, arr_2):
    d = dict()
    w = dict()
    for i in (arr_1):
       d[i] = None
    for j in (arr_2):

    return

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = ['Janury', 'Feb', 'March']
print(func(a,b))
```

Comment: Не могу понять как None  заменить на значения из b. Заранее благодарю всех за ответы!

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос какой ответ вы ожидаете в данном примере.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

используйте функцию `zip`:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = ['first', 'second', 'third']

res = dict(zip(x, y))

print(res)
```

функция `zip` создает пары элементов из двух списков, а `dict()` преобразует пары в ключ-значение

только стоит учесть один момент - если в массивах разное кол-во элементов, то `zip` создаст пары по `min(len(x), len(y))` элементам (например, в одном массиве 10 элементов, в другом - 15 элементов, `zip` создаст первые 10 пар), так что если  нужно общее решение, стоит дополнить меньший массив чем-нибудь до большего размера вначале

Comment: Ещё есть `zip_longest`.